# How to pass locations in a tableview cell? when select a cell navigate to the location?

Tags: swift, location, tableview, mapkit

the problem that i want to passee 4 countries inside a tableview cells, when select a cell goes to it's country label.

what I want that when press fist cell goes to Brooklyn and the second to Queesn..etc

can someone please assist me?

..inside a tableview cell, each country in  a cell and when press the cell goes to it's country? how i can do it

I want to pass these location data

this the cocde that i used so far.. the problem that when i select a cell it draw a line through all the locations.

and  the delegate function

```
var countryArray = ["Brooklyn", "Queens", "Manhattan", "The Bronx"]
let coordinates = [ (CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.6782, longitude: 73.9442)), (CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7282, longitude: 73.7949)), (CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.7831, longitude: 73.9712)), (CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.8448, longitude: 73.8648)) ]


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return countryArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let locationCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: LocationTableViewCell.locationCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! LocationTableViewCell
    locationCell.countryLable.text = countryArray[indexPath.row]
    // getting the location based on the country name
    LocationManger.sharedLocationManager.findLocations(with: countryArray, coordinates: coordinates) { location in
        self.locationArray = location
        print("the current location is(location)")
    }
    // hide the car cell separator
    locationCell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
    // remove the animation when tapping the cell
    locationCell.selectionStyle = .none
    return locationCell
    
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    currentLocationTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    // notify map controller to show pin at selected place
    print(locationArray.count)
    print(coordinates)
    let location = locationArray[indexPath.row].coordinates
    self.delegate?.SearchLocationController(self, didSelectLocationWith: location)
}

extension SearchLocationController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {
            return nil
        }
        // set a custom pin
        var annotaionView = map.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "custom")
        
        if annotaionView == nil {
            // create the view
            annotaionView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "custom")
            // taping in the point
            annotaionView?.canShowCallout = true
            annotaionView?.image = UIImage(named: "blueLocation")
        }
        else {
            annotaionView?.annotation = annotation
        }
        return annotaionView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about this wrong. Table view cells are **views**. They do not store data, they provide a view into data.

You want a model that holds an array of data, and your table view data source methods should take that data and install it into the cell for the specified IndexPath.

Use an array of structs where each element holds all the data you need: city names, their coordinates, etc.

When the user selects a cell, use the indexPath of the selected cell to look up the data for that cell in your array of structs, and pass the needed data to the view controller that will display your data (your SearchLocationController.)